# summarize two CSS-keyframes

Tags: css

I've two css-keyframes. They only differentiate by one statement:

```
@keyframes expand-t{
0%{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
}
50%{
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 100;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
100%{
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;
}

}
@keyframes expand-b{

0%{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
}
50%{
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 100;

    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
100%{
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;
}

}
```

At **50%** in the `expand-t` I change the `top` to *0* while I change the `top` in `expand-b` to *50%*. The rest of the code is similar.
How can I summarize this to avoid redundand code?

PS: I won't use LESS or SCSS or what ever. When possible a CSS-only way!

Comment: This question is potentially more suitable more for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Dunno - I mean, it's not "is this good style", it's "this is what I want, is there a way to do it within the constraints of the language".  Much like "How can I abstract out the common code from these Java classes", except with CSS.

Comment: @kunalbhat: Is it mossible to move this question to this site or should I delete this one here and post it new on the codereview site?

Comment: @cloudfeet: ... What?

Comment: @user - I was responding to kunalbhat, saying that I personally thought this was an OK place to ask the question.  You can move it if you like, though. :)

Comment: @cloudfeet: Ah. Haha sorry :D

Comment: @kunalbhat: Postet it there. And there they say I should post it here... They closed the question because it is off topic there... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31737/summarize-two-css-keyframes ...

Comment: @cloudfeet et al that's why I said 'potentially' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't summarize the keyframes without some kind of preprocessor.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes):

> If multiple keyframe sets exist for a given name, the last one encountered is used. @keyframes rules don't cascade, so animations never drive keyframes from more than one rule set.